# A knight's movement

Tags: chess, terminology

In chess, the knight moves in an 'L' shape.  I have not found any additional name for this.  Does this movement have a name other than 'L' shaped?

Comment: Although this is on topic here; you might have better luck with a question like this over at chess.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The move a Knight makes is typically called either a "*Knight's move*", or "*L-Shaped*".

There aren't really any more common names than those, as the Knight and it's move are both relatively unique, and predate western chess; being one of two pieces that were directly imported from Chaturanga (the other is the Rook) in their current form.

You will occasionally find referrences to the move as a "*Knight's Leap*" or "*Knight's Jump*", but those usages are uncommon.

Comment: It's also [called a knight's move in go](https://senseis.xmp.net/?KnightSMove) (which, of course doesn't even have knights).

Answer (score 3):

We call it "dhai chaal" (in hindi) or 2.5 steps (in english) in India.